# pthread/uthread type variable

Tags: c, pthreads

In studying uthreads (from pthreads), I have come across the following line of code:

```
uthread_t uthread_create (void* (*start_proc)(void*), void* start_arg)
```

I am not sure what `uthread_create()` is taking as the first parameter. Is it taking pointer to no specific type casted to pointer to type start_proc? Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument is a function pointer.  `start_proc` points to a function that takes a single `void *` parameter and returns a `void *`, which in this case is the entry point for a thread.  Also, the second argument to `uthread_create` is the parameter which will get passed to `start_proc` when it is called.

A function like this would satisfy the function pointer:

```
void *my_thread(void *p)
{
    char *s = p;
    printf("s=%s", s);
    return NULL;
}
```

And you could call `uthread_create` like this:

```
uthread_t tid;
char str[] = "test string";
tid = uthread_create(my_thread, str);
```